# how can I get product Weight for single tableview cell and show the amount of the product which product weight is selected?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

```
`{
    "LAP":[ \[][1]
        {
            "id": "31",
            "product_name": "Popcorn Cake",
            "product_name_arab": "كيك الفشار",
            "product_description": null,
            "product_description_arab": null,
            "img_url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0133/3300/4347/products/popcorn_cake_590x.jpg",
            "product_details": [
                {
                    "price_id": "15",
                    "product_weight": "25 CM",
                    "product_demo_amount": "230",
                    "product_amount": "225"
                },
                {
                    "price_id": "16",
                    "product_weight": "20 CM",
                    "product_demo_amount": "180",
                    "product_amount": "175"
                },
                {
                    "price_id": "17",
                    "product_weight": "15 CM",
                    "product_demo_amount": "125",
                    "product_amount": "120"
                }
            ],
            "available": "1",
            "recommended": null,
            "type": "1"
        }
    ]
}`
`var item: productList!
  let productRate = item.product_details
 for prductRatein in productRate! {
print("product_weight",prductRatein.product_weight)
 self.productRate.text = prductRatein.product_amount! 
 self.productSize.setTitle(prductRatein.product_weight, for: .normal)
}`


`let dropDown = DropDown()
 dropDown.anchorView = self.productSize
 dropDown.dataSource = productDetails.map{$0.product_weight!
}`
```

in the table view, I need to show the product weight in one button and if I change the product weight, I need to show the amount of the product which product weight is selected?.
    [need to show product weight list but it showing onely one but there are 3 weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsk3g.png)

Comment: There is no clear question asked and no code showing your current attempt. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: in tableview i have one dropdown button in that I need to show the product weight for product. like that, I have a list of products in that there will be 2 or 3 kids of weight need to show their weight separate product in dropdown.